# Reading a JSON File in a Java Class of a Dynamic web project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to read a JSON file to in a java class of a dynamic web project (not in a servlet).
Can someone tell how to read the resource(JSON file) which is placed in WEB-INF folder of the project.

Can someone tell how to achieve this?

Comment: getResourceAsStream but getServletContext won't be available in plain java classes so unable to get the resource

Answer (score 0):

Two basic options.

a) use ServletConfig.getServletContext() to obtain the currently active servlet context. This can only work IF the code is executed as part of an actual servlet request, otherwise there simply is no active servlet context to speak of.

b) actually put the file on the classpath, so that it ends up in WEB-INF/classes or inside a jar in WEB-INF/lib; then you can load it from any class in your application using getClass().getResourceAsStream() or getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(), at any time.

Option b) has the added benefit of also working in any type of Java application so it is nice and portable. It can also work in a unit test for example.